# How to sum date column(hh:mm:ss)

Tags: sql

I have column name as Time-diff. this column differences by two dates.

I need to sum all Time-diff columns like Total spent of hours.

It would be like,

```
Time-diff
00:30:00
00.10:00
01.00.00

i get like this:

CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(23),DateOut,121) AS DATETIME)-
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(23),DateIn,121)AS DATETIME),8) Time-diff
```

i need to sum Time-diff column as like below:

```
the output should be:01:40:00
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Which datatype is that column? An `interval` or `time`?

Comment: column datatype is DATETIME

Comment: And which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Seems to be T-SQL in MSSQL. The example worked in that environment anyway.

Comment: -1 For not providing the DBMS while asking a DBMS-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need all those casts. You go from date to varchar and back to date. You can get the same result by just

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateOut - DateIn, 8) [Time-diff]
```

and you can get the output you are looking for by using a different query to sum and then cast that output.

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
dateadd(s, sum(datediff(s, DateIn, DateOut)), getdate()) - getDate(),8)
from yourTable
```

This just gets a date diff in seconds of each row and sums it. Then uses the same method you used previously but this time uses the time difference calculated by the sum of each row

Comment: You're calling getdate() twice.  Are you worried about introducing an error?

Comment: @brad, valid point but would be unlikely. We could of course CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) each of those getDate()'s but to keep the example simpler and more readable i'll leave that omitted.

Comment: I think that you're right, that it would be unlikely to introduce an error.  If an error were introduced it would be small.  However if an error were introduced using convert(date,getdate()) around midnight, it might be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing directly from Jas with a small tweak;

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(8),
       dateadd(s, sum(datediff(s, DateIn, DateOut)), '1/1/1900')
       ,8)
  from yourTable
```